# Copying or Updating Data from One Excel sheet to Another, Both online on SharePoint

Tags: excel, sharepoint, power-automate, excel-online

hope you have a nice day/evening ahead,

I'm very much noob and wanted to get around this.

Have two Excel Files: (A) and (B) on a SharePoint.

The excel file (B) (A tracker) is updated everyday has one sheet only.

I need the update to reflect on File(A) [which has 3 sheets, Excel File B is duplicate of one of these 3sheets].

Note that within File (A) there are 3 sheets. One of them is entirely duplicate of File (B).

File (B) - Updated
Changes should reflect on Sheet 2 of File(A).

If it cannot be linked i.e. if it cannot be updated, is there a way, I can copy the contents without too much manual work?

Thank you for any help in advance. May this year be kind to you :)

Created local copies and tried to sync via onedrive but that is not an option anymore as my organization does not allow one drive access

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make a direct cell-for-cell link from B to A you could use a formula like this on A:

```
='https://COMPANYNAME-my.sharepoint.com/personal/COMPANYNAME/Documents/Team/[NAME OF SPREADSHEET B.xlsx]PAGENAME'!A1
```

Modify the url based on what you can see for your spreadsheet.

Then copy the formula to the whole sheet. In theory changes on B should show up straight away on A (in practise sometimes the link is a little slow).